# How to do SNS filtering with prefix matching on String.Array type message attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, filtering, amazon-sns, prefix

Is there a way to apply SNS filtering to match all messages that has message attribute 'MyMessageAttribute  ' ( type = String.Array ) and any of its value start with "MyPrefix" ?

I have searched on google and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latestbut couldn't find any example

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "MyMessageAttribute": [
    {
      "prefix": "MyPrefix"
    }
  ]
}
```

In array attributes, the filters match if any of the array values matches the filter.

The closest thing to documenting this fact they have is the example for `anything-but` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/string-value-matching.html):

> Moreover, it matches the following message attribute (because it contains a value that isn't rugby or tennis):
>
> ```
> "customer_interests": {"Type": "String.Array", "Value": "[\"rugby\", \"baseball\"]"}
> ```

, but I can assure you that it works.